# Using PHP to create folders based on a list

Tags: php, list, directory

Hi I am working on a PHP/MySQL project and need some help.

Specifically I am working on an online document library.

I have set up my project so that when I create a new client, it automatically creates them a folder (based on their auto integer primary key), with two sub folders `library` and `projects`, the code looks like this:

```
$folder = "ClientFiles/" . $keys["companypk"]; if (!file_exists($folder)) { mkdir($folder, 0777, true);};
$folder = "ClientFiles/" . $keys["companypk"] . "/library"; if (!file_exists($folder)) { mkdir($folder, 0777, true);};
$folder = "ClientFiles/" . $keys["companypk"] . "/projects"; if (!file_exists($folder)) { mkdir($folder, 0777, true);};
```

and it works very nicely.

However this is where I need help.

I have another table called `adminfolders`, which I use to write a list of standard folders I want to populate within the library when I add a client (i.e. to add to the above code). So if I have 10 folder names in that list I want those 10 sub-folders created in the `$folder = "ClientFiles/" . $keys["companypk"] . "/library"` directory.

Any ideas please?

Updated:

Sorry I didnt realise it didnt make much sense, i'm new to this really.

OK, i'll try and make it a bit esaier to understand, when i add a new company to my 'clients' table, the top 3 lines of code automatically create a parent folder for that company with two sub folders called "library" and "projects".

I want to go one step further and create sub folders at the same time, within the clientfolder/library child folder.

The problem is that this is not a static list of folders, i have created a table called adminfolders, which i populate with folder names, say "drawings", "procedures", etc, the intention is that i want some code that looks at that table and creates a folder for each item in this list, so creating a way to create folders dynamically based on a list in another table?  hope that makes more sense

Comment: I read the question 3 times, still can't understand what you need or what your problem is.

Comment: @TasosBitsios you and me both. Small thing for OP, you don't need semi colons at the end of the if statement ie `if(){};`, should be `if(){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a PDO connection named $db and your adminfolders table has a column named folderName that holds the name of the folders to be created:

```
$sql = "SELECT folderName FROM adminfolders;";

$stmt = $db->execute($sql);

$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($results as $row)
{
 $folder = "ClientFiles/" . $keys["companypk"] . "/library/" . $row["folderName"];
 mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that is EXACTLY what i wanted, i bow to you

Comment: @user3169979 No need to bow, just mark it as the correct answer and give it an upvote :)

Comment: Didnt quite work, i'm using a php code generated called PHPRunner, which has its own events setup and core programming, you can add events to it,, i've had to change it to something like this, but not working...$rs=db_query("select foldername from adminfolders");
$data=db_fetch_array($rs);
foreach($data as $row)
{
 $folder = "ClientFiles/" . $keys["companypk"] . "/library/" . $row["folderName"];
 mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
}

Comment: @user3169979 Try changing `$row["folderName"]` to `$row["foldername"]` to match the lack of camelCase used in your query.

Comment: @user3169979 And you're placing this code immediately after the functioning code that you gave above?  Want to paste in what you have now?

Comment: This method may not work `mkdir($folder, 0777, true);` You may need to use `mkdir($folder); chmod($folder, 0777);` instead, which may be one of the problems. @user3169979 tell us what error messages you're getting.

Comment: 1. 2;
2. Missing argument 2 for db_query(), called in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites\Cloud ISO Portal\include\companies_events.php on line 43 and defined;
3. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sites\Cloud ISO Portal\include\dbconnection.my.mysqli.php;
4. 37;
5. Array ( [qstring] => select foldername from adminfolders ) ;

Comment: this is full code on that page, everthing worked until added this new code

Comment: Looks like you need to learn how to use your db methods.  Check this link for a couple examples of using db_query() in PHPRunner:  http://xlinesoft.com/phprunner/docs/check_if_specific_record_exists.htm

Comment: Made an error, I deleted my previous comment. The last semi-colon in `mkdir($folder, 0777, true);};` and the others shouldn't be there. It should be `mkdir($folder, 0777, true);}` @user3169979

Comment: Am starting to think that this `$keys["companypk"] . "/library/" . $row["folderName"]` shouldn't have quotes. Maybe this will make it fire up `$keys[companypk] . "/library/" . $row[folderName]` since now it's dealing with arrays and not treated as singles as originally done. @user3169979

Comment: no the keys with "" arent the problem as this works for the other events, its just this one, as Patrick says, it looks like i need to use DAL to do query

Comment: ok i have gone back to original statement given by Patrick, there was a mistake in first line, the ; needed to be after the ".  Put this in and it is now working better but getting this message...Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Comment: @user3169979 If you're trying to use the code exactly as I gave it, remember that it is assuming that $db is a PDO connection.  If you're wanting to use whatever db connection PHPRunner provides, you'll need slightly different code.  If you do want to use PDO but don't know how, that's a different story (start by looking here http://us1.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: ok, ive got the dal part working and first part is working great, it now appears there is a problem with the folder making part of code, 
//create dynamic list of folders based on admin folder content
$sql = "select foldername from adminfolders";
$rs = CustomQuery($sql);
$data = CustomQuery($sql);
$results = $rs;

foreach($results as $row)
{
 $folder = "ClientFiles/" . $keys["companypk"] . "/library/" . $row["foldername"];
 mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
}

Produces this error..."mkdir(): File exists", i've checked and it doesnt so guessing its a loop issue?  not sure

Comment: @user3169979 Do some basic debugging. Before the `foreach`, toss in a `print_r($results);exit;` and see what it displays. Is it what you're expecting? If so, remove that and then replace the `mkdir` line with `echo $folder."<br/>"`. Are the folder paths as expected?

Comment: feel i am so close, i've done that and it is giving me following results, which looks correct as there are 6 standard folders in the admin list...mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 6 [type] => 0 )

Comment: ah, the 2nd instruction for debugging failed, the path it gives in each line is same ie ClientFiles/23/projects, it isnt doing the foldername for each record in adminfolder table, yet first part of debug sees there are 6

Comment: @user3169979 Try replacing `foreach($results as $row)` with `while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc())`  I highly recommend doing some more reading about the db connection provided by PHPRunner and how to use it. I'm not sure if what I'm giving you will work, but at this point we're quite far off from the original question and more into a PHPRunner tutorial.

Comment: @user3169979 Click the up arrow/triangle next to the answer and there should also be a link or button or something to mark/select as the correct answer